# Nvidia driver installed, but not working!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I was installing *cuda-8.0* for my project and followed this link, which asked me to download Nvidia Driver using .run file:
http://queirozf.com/entries/installing-cuda-tk-and-tensorflow-on-a-clean-ubuntu-16-04-install
along with which I blacklisted *Nouveau* Driver.
The installation was done by executing `sudo service lightdm stop` and then running the .run file.
Initially I faced some difficulties like login loop and black screen, but later solved them.
Now, when i try to execute commands like:
*command:* `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` , gives output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0782]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 280
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

*command:*  `glxinfo | grep OpenGL | grep renderer`, gives the output:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2
```

*command:* `sudo lshw -c video`, gives the output:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:280 memory:d4000000-d4ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
```

*command:* `lsmod | grep nv`, gives the output:

```
nvidia_uvm            647168  0
nvidia_drm             49152  0
nvidia_modeset        790528  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              12144640  2 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 i915,nvidia_drm
drm                   368640  6 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
```

I think, the Nvidia driver is installed, but still not activated as the kernel driver.
Can someone help me figuring out the problem and how to solve it?
Please ask if any other info is needed.
BTW, driver version is *NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39* on *Ubuntu 16.04*

**Update 1:**
[screenshot of distorted window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7THT.jpg)

Comment: You have hybrid graphics. You need to enable Nvidia using `nvidia-prime`.

Comment: I did, `sudo prime-select nvidia`, it gives me following errors : `Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled`

Comment: That was a bad idea to install drivers from a .run file. If you installed it a normal way from the repos, it should work OK. Uninstall .run and use the repos.

Comment: can you please give me link of the repos or a blog from which i can refer?

Comment: Run the `.run` file with `--uninstall` parameter and then install drivers by `sudo apt install nvidia-375`. There is a ton of guides how to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: What if I do :`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove `. Will the result still be the same?

Comment: If you installed a driver from a .run file it will not be removed this way.

Comment: I have installed the driver again by your method, but the graphics are now behaving wierdly. 1)The text flickers whenever i scroll web page up and down. 2) All windows have a got a strange looking RBG boundary around them! (as shown in update)

Comment: This is a known bug on some adapters after suspend mostly. I suggest installing `nvidia-381` from the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`